# Is "+" slower than "CONCAT" for large strings?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concat, sql-server-2022, standard-edition

I have always thought that [CONCAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function is actually a wrapper over the [+ (String Concatenation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/string-concatenation-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) with some additional checks in order to make our life more easier.

I have not found any internal details about how the functions are implemented. As to the performance, [it seems](https://stevestedman.com/2021/01/performance-string-concatenation-in-sql-server/) that there is overhead for calling `CONCAT` when data is concatenating in a loop (which seems normal as there are additional handles for NULLs).

Few days ago, a dev modified some string concatenation code (from `+` to `CONCAT)` because did not like the syntax and told me it became faster.

In order to check the case, I have used the following code:

```
DECLARE @V1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@V2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@V3 NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @R NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @V1 = REPLICATE(CAST('V1' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 50000000)
       ,@V2 = REPLICATE(CAST('V2' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 50000000)
       ,@V3 = REPLICATE(CAST('V3' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 50000000);
```

where this is variant one:

```
SELECT @R = CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '{some small text}' + ISNULL(@V1, '{}') + ISNULL(@V2, '{}') + ISNULL(@V3, '{}'); 
SELECT LEN(@R); -- 1200000017
```

and this is variant two:

```
SELECT @R = CONCAT('{some small text}',ISNULL(@V1, '{}'), ISNULL(@V2, '{}'), ISNULL(@V3, '{}'))
SELECT LEN(@R); -- 1200000017
```

For smaller strings, there is no differences. At some point, the `CONCAT` variant becomes faster:

[image]

I wonder if someone can share any internals or explains the behavior as it seems that there  might be a rule that it's better to concatenate large strings using `CONCAT`.

Version:

*Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU8) (KB5029666) - 16.0.4075.1 (X64)
Aug 23 2023 14:04:50
Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Standard 10.0  (Build 17763: ) (Hypervisor)*

---

The exact script looks like the following:

```
DECLARE @V1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@V2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
       ,@V3 NVARCHAR(MAX);

DECLARE @R NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT  @V1 = REPLICATE(CAST('V1' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 50000000)
       ,@V2 = REPLICATE(CAST('V2' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 50000000)
       ,@V3 = REPLICATE(CAST('V3' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 50000000);



--SELECT @R = CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '{some small text}' + ISNULL(@V1, '{}') + ISNULL(@V2, '{}') + ISNULL(@V3, '{}'); -- 00:00:45 -- 00:01:22 -- 00:01:20
--SELECT LEN(@R); -- 300000017

SELECT @R = CONCAT('{some small text}',ISNULL(@V1, '{}'), ISNULL(@V2, '{}'), ISNULL(@V3, '{}')) -- 00:00:11 -- 00:00:16 -- 00:00:10
SELECT LEN(@R); -- 300000017
```

where I am changing the last argument of the REPLICATE functions in order to generate larger strings for the concatenation. Then, I am executing each variant three times.

Comment: Yes, `+` is less optimized than `CONCAT`. The upside is that `CONCAT` has better legibility as your code base scales up or if you have prebaked scripts for migrations, DB backups, or overall routing maintenance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Is "+" slower than "CONCAT" for large strings?

Looks that way. From looking at the pages allocated and deallocated in `tempdb` for storage of this LOB data it looks like each instance of the `+` ends up creating a new string and allocating and deallocating pages for it in `tempdb` (of which only the final one is needed).

Whereas `CONCAT` just uses the pages required for the size of the final result and does not degrade as more `+` are added by allocating pages for (and writing) ultimately unneeded intermediate strings.

| Method | newly_allocated_pages | newly_deallocated_pages | new_in_use_pages |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| + | 249280 | 249280 | 0 |
| Concat | 99696 | 99696 | 0 |

For my code below - which includes an extra `@V4` concatenation vs the question - the data length of the final result is 800,000,034 bytes (762.94 MiB). The `CONCAT` method allocated 99,696 pages. An average of 8024.4 bytes per page. SQL Server uses 8KiB pages but some space is needed for page header (and other) overhead.

For `+` it allocates 249,280 pages (~1.9 GiB) you can see how it builds up to this number by trying the intermediate expressions as below (each step uses a reasonable number of additional pages for the data length of its result but this is *as well as* the page usage of the preceding steps not *instead of*) so the ratio of "extra" pages allocated increases as more `+` are added.

| Expression | Datalength | pages_allocated | Datalength/pages_allocated | Diff | DataLength/Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '{some small text}' | 34 | 0 |  | 0 |  |
| CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '{some small text}' + ISNULL(@V1, '{}') | 200000034 | 24920 | 8025.683547 | 24920 | 8025.683547 |
| CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '{some small text}' + ISNULL(@V1, '{}') + ISNULL(@V2, '{}') | 400000034 | 74768 | 5349.882757 | 49848 | 8024.39484 |
| CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '{some small text}' + ISNULL(@V1, '{}') + ISNULL(@V2, '{}') + ISNULL(@V3, '{}') | 600000034 | 149552 | 4011.982682 | 74784 | 8023.107001 |
| CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '{some small text}' + ISNULL(@V1, '{}') + ISNULL(@V2, '{}') + ISNULL(@V3, '{}') + ISNULL(@V4, '{}') | 800000034 | 249280 | 3209.242755 | 99728 | 8021.81969 |

As [David Browne - Microsoft](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/126936/david-browne-microsoft) says in the comments...

> This makes sense as `+` is a binary operator, and `CONCAT` is an
> `N-ary` function. So without special optimization `a+b+c` is evaluated
> as `(a+b)+c`, requiring two new strings. While `CONCAT(A,B,C)` can
> more easily just build one new string

This distinction also shows up in truncation behaviour.

For the below in the first case the first two strings concatenated are non max data types and the result is truncated to `8000` bytes. Then it is concatenated to a `max` type and the resultant string is `max` and the final concatenation succeeds with no truncation.

`CONCAT` can see that it has a `MAX` type passed in as a parameter and avoids this initial truncation.

```
DECLARE @X VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

--14000
SELECT  DATALENGTH(REPLICATE('A', 6000) + REPLICATE('B', 6000) + @X + REPLICATE('C', 6000)) 

--18000
SELECT  DATALENGTH(CONCAT(REPLICATE('A', 6000), REPLICATE('A', 6000) , @X, REPLICATE('C', 6000)))
```

**Script used for seeing page allocations**

In the script below I don't assign to the `@R` variable as this itself requires pages to be allocated and I am just focussing on the pages used by the concatenation methods.

```
DECLARE @TestConcat BIT = 0 /*Set to 0 for "+" and 1 for "Concat"*/
       ,@internal_objects_alloc_page_count1 BIGINT
       ,@internal_objects_alloc_page_count2 BIGINT
       ,@internal_objects_dealloc_page_count1 BIGINT
       ,@internal_objects_dealloc_page_count2 BIGINT
       ,@V1 NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE(CAST('V1' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 50000000)
       ,@V2 NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE(CAST('V2' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 50000000)
       ,@V3 NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE(CAST('V3' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 50000000)
       ,@V4 NVARCHAR(MAX) = REPLICATE(CAST('V4' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), 50000000);

--Initial state after above variables assigned and before concatenation
SELECT @internal_objects_alloc_page_count1 = internal_objects_alloc_page_count, 
       @internal_objects_dealloc_page_count1 = internal_objects_dealloc_page_count
from sys.dm_db_task_space_usage
WHERE session_id = @@spid;

IF @TestConcat = 1
    SELECT DATALENGTH(CONCAT('{some small text}',ISNULL(@V1, '{}'), ISNULL(@V2, '{}'), ISNULL(@V3, '{}'), ISNULL(@V4, '{}')));
ELSE
    SELECT DATALENGTH(CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + '{some small text}' + ISNULL(@V1, '{}') + ISNULL(@V2, '{}') + ISNULL(@V3, '{}') + ISNULL(@V4, '{}'));

--State after concatenation completed
SELECT @internal_objects_alloc_page_count2 = internal_objects_alloc_page_count, 
       @internal_objects_dealloc_page_count2 = internal_objects_dealloc_page_count
from sys.dm_db_task_space_usage
WHERE session_id = @@spid;

-- Diff between the two states 
SELECT newly_allocated_pages = @internal_objects_alloc_page_count2-@internal_objects_alloc_page_count1 ,
       newly_deallocated_pages = @internal_objects_dealloc_page_count2-@internal_objects_dealloc_page_count1 ,
       new_in_use_pages = (@internal_objects_alloc_page_count2 - @internal_objects_dealloc_page_count2) - (@internal_objects_alloc_page_count1 - @internal_objects_dealloc_page_count1);
```

Comment: This is the kind of thing that you would really expect the parser to solve for you. If it's willing to change `CASE WHEN` in to a form that I didn't actually write it in, then it should do the same for string concatenation.

Comment: @J.Mini - It wouldn't be able to just do a quick rewrite of `+` ... `+` ... `+` to `CONCAT(..., ..., ...)` as they have different behaviours w.r.t. `NULL` and also truncation and also other things (e.g. see `SELECT '1' + '2' + 3, CONCAT('1', '2', 3)`) - so it would need an `N-ary` version with the same behaviour to not change the result